# Different Coordinate system in r.water.outlet

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm trying to use the r.water.outlet when selecting the coordinate from the map it changes the coordinate system as in the picture. I make sure all the layers and the project have the same coordinate system so I'm not sure where the problem could be coming from... [image]

Comment: Looks like you are using the GRASS module within QGIS. What is the project CRS. (from your screen shot, it is probably 3857...)

Comment: The project CRS is also 32632, is the first thing I set up at the beggining

Comment: But note the "Coordinate of outlet point" has x-y in EPSG:3857